# Is there such a thing as a comparison operator expressable with basic operations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there an operator that takes two values and returns 1 when they are equal and 0 if they are not equal?

For instance:

4 OP 5 = 0

1 OP 1 = 1

etc.

I would prefer this to be expressed in the most basic operations, which I personally prefer to include the following 8:

**addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, power raising, limits, summation, and the floor function**

Answer (score 3):

(This answers the original question only.)

Yes; a mathematician might denote this value $[x=y]$, where $[\Box]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). E.g. $$[4 = 5] = 0, \qquad [1=1] = 1$$

There's a slight problem with this, namely that $[\Box ]$ is one of the most overloaded notations in all of mathematics. Perhaps to get around this, or maybe because its a little prettier, the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) is still sometimes used; it can be defined as follows.

$$\delta_{x,y} = [x=y]$$

Personally, I avoid the Kronecker notation and just stick to $[\Box]$, because it is imo unnecessary.

Another option is to use $\delta$ as an alternative symbol for the Iverson bracket; so we could write things like $\delta_{x=y}$ and $\delta_{x<y},$ etc. This isn't standard, though, so be sure to tell the reader what you mean if you wish to use it. But anyway, this is probably a bit more readable than the Iverson bracket notation:

$$(\delta_{4=5}) = 0, \qquad (\delta_{1=1}) = 1$$

Actually, I think the best solution would be for someone to come up with (and proceed to popularize) a symbol that is a composite of $0$ and $1$; something that looks a bit like $\phi,$ but unitalicized and with more of the details of $1$. Then we can write things like $\phi_{x=y}$ and $\varphi_{x>y}$ etc., and this would solve the problem that $[\Box]$ is just massively overloaded and not very readable. It would also solve the problem that sometimes we want to use $\delta$ for something else entirely, like the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, that's fine. You can accept your own answer. FWIWm I would have phrased the question more like: "Can the function $\mathop{\lambda}_{x,y:\mathbb{R}} [x=y]$ be expressed using only the Heaviside step function and the usual arithmetical operations?" or some such.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, what do you mean by "its an illusion"?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, not quite following...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, you seem to be saying that there's this special set of basic operations that are somehow "more fundamental" and that everything has to be expressed in terms of these basic operations. I don't really agree with this.

Comment: The Kronecker $\delta$ predates the Iverson bracket by a couple of decades. Thus your "Perhaps to get around this" sounds a little odd. (And a definition in terms of Iverson brackets is anachronistic.)

Comment: Most expositions of mathematics that aren't completely painful are massively anachronistic @DanielFischer. In any event, to explain why the Kronecker delta function is still sometimes used, you have to deal with mathematics as it is today, and the only explanation I can find regarding why $\delta_{x,y}$ is still used to today is that its less overloaded than $[\Box]$, and perhaps a little prettier.

Comment: I wasn't complaining about the anachronism. However, I can offer an alternative explanation why people use the Kronecker $\delta$: It's just better known. People know $\delta$ and learn about it, while the Iverson bracket was never once mentioned when I was at university. I've learned about it much later. Perhaps that has changed since then and now people get told about Iverson brackets in university, but I'm not that old that the effect had time to completely vanish.